# Перевести имя участника Community

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, дух-сообщества

[Участник Community](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) - автоматический модератор всех сайтов StackExchange. Следует ли перевести его имя на русском? Если следует, как?

Comment: Модераторы могут отредактировать профиль. Вопрос, надо ли?

Comment: @Nofate: это часть перевода. Сферическому русскоязычному пользователю в вакууме слово "community" неизвестно.

Comment: Одна баба сказала, Трансцендентный,  НЛО, добрая фея

Comment: Конь в пальто еще забыл.

Comment: @igumnov: НЛО это намек на Хабр?

Comment: @Nick Каждый понимает в меру своей испорченности.

Comment: Как мне кажется, можно отметить выбранный ответ правильным.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Не понял, какой ответ был выбранным? Кажется, что имя участника Community еще не изменилось.

Comment: @PeterOlson В большинстве случаев, у нас тоталитаризм большинства. То есть правильный тот, который набрал больше голосов, конечно, если нет явных возражений.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Зачем мне выбрать ответ? Как вы сказали, выбор сообщества - это главное. Мой личний выбор не добавляет никакой полезной информации. И количество голосов может измениться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: думаю, принять ответ стоит после того, как перевод уйдет в продакшен. Это будет означать, по крайней мере, что голосование закрыто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Задача уже имеется в трекере и лишь ждет своего часа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: на всякий случай: можно в тот же тикет добавить это: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/964/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin Готово!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Дух сообщества

Заменить на Дух сообщества

Comment: «добрый дух сообщества», «добрый дух», «коллективный дух»

Comment: призрак коммунизма

Comment: @PashaPash, невидимая рука.

Answer (score 9):

#### Сообщество

Перевести, так как это часть перевода интерфейса сайта.

Comment: «коллектив», «команда», «общественность», «община», «социум»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin community удаляет посты. дословный перевод может быть неправильно понят. "Сообщество удалило ваш пост"

Comment: @PashaPash, я вообще-то за электроника. и сыроежкина.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: чего-то его заминусовали.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, может быть, вспоминают песенку из фильма, и печалятся, что до сих пор не роботы вкалывают, а человек.

Answer (score 9):

#### Система

Вариант - назвать "Система". В принципе, "Community" - технический персонаж, не представляющий кого-то конкретного, но и "всё сообщество" имхо немного большое имя для одного фактически пользователя.

Comment: «Борись против системы» ))

Comment: по-моему, может порождать не самые лучшие ассоциации.

Answer (score 8):

#### Большой Брат

Следит за тобой и периодически поднимает посты.

Comment: Хороший вариант.

Answer (score 7):

#### Электроник

В честь одного из первых (наверняка) и самых знаменитых роботов в нашей научной фантастике.

Родной и близкий нам персонаж.

> Ты — человек,
> Ты сильный и смелый,
> Своими руками судьбу свою делай!
> Иди против ветра, на месте не стой,
> Пойми — не бывает дороги простой.

Comment: Ой, я не знал, кто он такой. Надо смотреть больше советских фильмов)

Comment: @PeterOlson: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Робот Вертер, хоть и на пять лет "моложе" Электроника, может посоревноваться в известности =)

Comment: *В честь одного из первых (наверняка)* — сразу же вспоминается камилл с далёкой радуги, переживший проход «волны». написано в 63-м, а первая повесть про электроника — в 64-м. это просто то, что сразу же приходит в голову.

Answer (score 2):

Заменить на **Вездесущий**.

Answer (score 2):

#### Мефистофель

Я — выдуманный персонаж, процесс-*демон*, который помогает поддерживать чистоту сайта! Я — часть той силы, что вечно хочет зла и вечно совершает благо.

Comment: Неплохо, но народ может стрематься, что за зверь этот "Мефистофель", а кто в теме, тот и святой водой ruSO обольет через свой ПК, ну и убьет его.

Comment: @Vesper: Если все религиозные фанатики лишатся ПК и доступа в интернет, я буду очень рад ))) Не рассчитываю на победу этого варианта, но ради лулзов предложил.

Comment: Если такая мощь вырвется в оффлайн, может поплохеть сразу всем. Да, "процесс-демон" фактически существует, пусть он и не один, но представь себе, ты задал вопрос, хоп прилетает "возможная копия (ссылка на вопрос)", ты смотришь, говоришь "да, подходит", и твой вопрос закрывает **Мефистофель**. Можно и в штаны наложить, не зная специфики.

Comment: @Vesper: да, ситуация будет необычная. Повторю, что вариант — для лулзов, его совершенно точно не примут, так что никакой опасности для оффлайна нет.

Answer (score 1):

Заменить на **Вахтёр**.

Comment: @PeterOlson Ограничение на длину ответа в 30 символов или больше. `Заменить на **Вахтёр**.` короче.

Comment: @Vesper Так, теперь понятно. Я исправил так, чтобы видимого допольнительного текста не было.

Comment: Классный вариант =D

Answer (score 0):

Заменить на **Завхоз**.

Answer (score -2):

#### Алёнушка

[Действия бота-модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) могут часто порождать негативные эмоции, например, даже с одобренными правками от анонимных пользователей авторы могут быть не согласны. Поэтому желательно, чтобы имя само по себе было умиротворяющим, многие другие представленные варианты слишком сухие безличные. В будущем персонифицированное имя легче в отставку отправить чем "Сообщество".

Answer (score -5):

**Интернетный**

Вот бывают дома в которых водятся домовые, в лесу -- лешие, а у нас -- Интернетный.

Comment: Думаю, это бы хорошо подошло для бота на Одноклассниках. А здесь — не подходит. Не могу сформулировать, почему.

Answer (score -7):

Перевод имени участника Community не нужен.