# Местоположение участника Community не переведено

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, дух-сообщества

Местоположение [участника Community](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) (то есть, [Дух сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/857/176684)) не переведено. Написано

> on the server farm

[image: on the server farm]

Как следует перевести местоположение этого участника?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вариант **"Дата-центр Stack Exchange"**. Это какое-никакое, а место, плюс привязывает ruSO к остальному сообществу Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

За вариант **«на серверной ферме»**

Comment: С серверными фермерами ))

Answer (score 3):

Вариант перевода - **"Тридевятое царство, тридесятое государство"**

Comment: Подумал, что в айтишном мире могло бы быть двавосьмое царство, четырешестнадцатое государство. )

Comment: Тогда можно еще что-нибудь взять из hexspeak, например: `0xDABBAD00`

Comment: о, такого ещё не слышал )

Answer (score 0):

вариант перевода: **на сервере**

Answer (score -3):

Перевод места этого пользователя не нужен.