# Что за странная правка Духом Сообщества?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, правки, дух-сообщества, https

[Вот сама правка.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/594652/revisions)

Зачем Дух Сообщества вообще исправляет, ведь он бот? Тем более, он не изменил ничего: всё, что помечено как исправленное, на самом деле так и осталось.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дух заменяет `http` ссылки на `https`. 3 года назад [решили перевести всё на https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/260198).

А чтобы посмотреть изменения, лучше выбирать разметку в две колонки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно полноценный dif'ы показывает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за правку. А я думал у духа поехала крыша ;)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica одно другое не исключает (¬‿¬ )

Comment: А кстати кто придумал такое креативное имя? По-английски он просто Community.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica сообщество так [решило](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/857/15479).

Comment: Ого, интересно я и не знал.

Comment: Но он же менял "как обычно" на "как обычно" и т.д зачем?Тут https не причем.

Comment: Смотрите [разметка в две колонки], будет видно, что именно исправлено.

Comment: @0xdb А, вот что.

Comment: Да, вот так. @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Добавте пожалуйста информацию из комментария выше в ответ, по видимому полезна.

Comment: @0xdb ух, я сначала и не понял, о чём речь. У меня всегда с разметкой dif'ы показывались. Я уже и забыл, что можно иначе ^_^"